# How to add foreign key to a serializer manually in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

while creating a branch, I want to add the id of a company(foreign key) according to the company of requested user.
Basically I want to add company id at serializer level only.

Here is my create function of branchViewset:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, context=context)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(company=request.user.owner)
```

and here is my serializer:

```
class CreateBranchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    def validate(self, attrs):
        try:
            user = self.context['request'].user
        except:
            raise CustomAPIException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                                     error_code='1006')
        return attrs
```

But while creating branch I get the error:

```
 company: field is required
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to exclude the `company` field in serializer's `Meta` class:

```
class CreateBranchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    class Meta:
         ...
         exclude = ['company']
```

Also, I suggest to prevent UnAuthorized requests in **views** using [permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated).

Comment: I am still getting this error:
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "company_id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Check  the value of `request.user.owner`, it is `None` and that is the reason for the error.